# How to theme Ubercart Checkout Complete page

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, ubercart, drupal-theming

I want to theme the page /cart/checkout/complete

I already saw the settings in admin/store/settings/checkout/settings, but they are not enough.
I want to add some HTML i.e. add a print button at the top of the page.

I would like to have a .tpl.php file to use as template, or otherwise, using an alternate checkout page, how to insert the texts defined in checkout settings.

I tried to make a uc_cart_complete_sale.tpl.php but it isn't called.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Template Suggestion documentation](http://drupal.org/node/1089656) you can provide a custom page.tpl.php for absolutely any path, so a template file with the following name would override `page.tpl.php` for the path `cart/checkout/complete`:

```
page--cart--checkout--complete.tpl.php
```

Be sure to clear Drupal's cache once you've create the file so the changes are picked up in the theme registry.

Comment: thanks very much, the document you suggested really saves me much time, I am Drupal newbie.

Answer (score 1):

After hard work, i found the template page.

It is:

```
page--cart--checkout--complete.tpl.php
```

remember to clear the cache

Answer (score 0):

firstly, you should probably check this page: admin/store/settings/checkout/edit/messages

there you can customize a header for the message displayed when the checkout completes.

other than that, you can implement some functions to alter this page. from a short look in the ubercart api maybe this function will do:  my_module_checkout_complete()  in [this link the guy says it worked](http://www.ubercart.org/forum/theming_and_design/16103/how_go_about_theming_cartcheckoutcomplete_page)

another function that should work is [theme_uc_cart_complete_sale](http://api.ubercart.org/api/function/theme_uc_cart_complete_sale/2)

there are other options, such as in your template.php check if this is /checkout/complete and do whatever you want. like this:

```
if (arg(0) == 'cart' && arg(1) == 'checkout' && arg(2) == 'complete')
```

and than redirect to your page. anyway, there are plenty of ways to accomplish this, but just naming a file 'uc_cart_complete_sale.tpl.php' won't work. sorry...

Comment: 1) about the admin page, this solution  could be a fast solution, but is not what i wanted, because i would like a control on the page with something like a node or page template
2) yes, the link is one of the best possible solution i found, but it's ubercart 2 and i hoped in ubercart 3 there was easiers solutions.
3) i don't want to modify the modules, then the solution is more complicated
4) possible solution, i thought another dirty solution modifying the page.tpl.php page

Comment: Ubercart 3 has this function, although the arguments changed to a $variables array containing "message" and "order" keys.

Answer (score 0):

In D6 at least, you can theme the message by overriding theme_uc_cart_complete_sale() - so if that's what you're after, theme the message by overriding that in your theme (for example, function mytheme_uc_cart_complete_sale($message, $order) {}